# Make the request keeping the parameter string array

Tags: c#, arrays, multipartform-data

I add 2 fields on my update request and I still didnt found a way to pass these 2 fields. I try someting link StringArrayContent, or ArrayContent that does not exist. I also try MultipartContent. How can I sent my request keeping **downloadableInternal** and **downloadableExternal** as string array?
The values usually are empty **[]** or **["original", "pdf"]**

```
return new ShowpadUpdateAssetRequest()
        {
            ExternalFileUri = externalFileUri,
            externalDate = externalDate,
            externalId = externalId,
            file = file,
            name = name,
            isDivisionShared = isDivisionShared,
            downloadableInternal = downloadableInternal,
            downloadableExternal = downloadableExternal,
            Url = url,
            Bearer = bearer,
            ResponseType = typeof(ShowpadUpdateAssetResponse),
            Content = new MultipartFormDataContent()
            {
                {new StringContent(externalId), nameof(externalId)},
                {new StringContent(name), nameof(name)},
                {new StringContent(externalDate), nameof(externalDate)},
                {new StringContent(isDivisionShared.ToString()), nameof(isDivisionShared) },                    
                {new StringContent(downloadableInternal.ToString())  ,nameof(downloadableInternal) },
                {new StringContent(downloadableExternal.ToString()) ,nameof(downloadableExternal) },
                {new ByteArrayContent((await fileContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync())), nameof(file), file}
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how your service handles the request. Here is an example you can try. You can also try to remove the `[]` suffix, some service may regard repetitive query parameters as an array.

```
var c = new MultipartFormDataContent();
var key = nameof(downloadableInternal) + "[]";
foreach(string data in downloadableInternal)
   c.Add(new StringContent(data), key);
```